# How Do You Apply Microdisplacements For Exporting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export

I've learned how to use microdisplacements and I think that they are very handy. However, I would like to use them in Unity Game Engine, so I would like to the microdisplacements to actually add new vertices and change the shape so that I can export it as a .fbx. If you can't, please tell me!

Comment: That is not possible as far as I know, Microdisplacement is internally generated dynamically at render time by the Cycles Render Engine and cannot, for the most part be exported. You can however use the same displacement map (if it is image based) on a regular *Displacement* modifier and achieve a similar effect, albeit at the expense of very high poly count

Answer (score 3):

The displacement input in the materials is for rendering inside of blender only. In order to get the effect in a game engine, you need to create the geometry by using a displacement modifier on the mesh.